# How to install and use the JMeter plugin "Standard Set"

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Hi I have downloaded the **Standard Set** from the [JMeter plugin site](http://jmeter-plugins.org/#/).

I installed it as it says here:
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginInstall/

The problem is that I don't get to see any option in the **Listener** Menu that let me add a new **Graphs Generator Listener** as described here:

http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/

I need to create a **Transactions per Second** graph , but I don't know how to do it.
I really appreciate if you could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any solution for this?  I've been struggling to get the Graphs Generator Listener plugin to work.  From Plugins manager this plugin is enabled , but no listeners are shown when adding a listener. Following @charlieS steps didn't work neither.  I need this plugin for the listener _Active Threads Over Time_

Comment: Rectified by opening the  ultimate thread group example provided at https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/ActiveThreadsOverTimeExample.jmx. Jmeter will trigger the missing plugins once the jmx file is opened.

Comment: Another guide worth mentioning which explains how to install plugins without any issue using the Plugins Manager: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/04/jmeter-plugins-install/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not see the extra elements in the menu, there is something wrong with your jmeter-plugins installation.

Make sure you unpacked the zip in the folder **above** 'bin', that is not clear in the instructions.

At the same folder level as 'bin' there should also be a 'lib', and beneath this, 'ext'.

Check that the 'ext' folder contains the jmeter plugin jar and other support files.

it should look like this:

```
|-apache-jmeter-2.11
| |-bin
| | |-jmeter.bat
| | |-ApacheJMeter.jar
| | |-...
| |-lib
| | |-ext
| | | |-JMeterPlugin-Standard.jar
| | | |-...
| | |-...
| |-...
|-...
```

Make sure you restart jmeter after moving these files.  If you have the jar in the right place, the extensions will be loaded and available from menu options.

Answer (score 0):

To install the JMeter Plugins,
-> Copy the JMeterPlugins.jar file from JMeterPlugins-VERSION.zip
-> Paste the file to JMETER_INSTALL_DIR/libexec/lib/ext